# Wrap Slick queries in Futures

Tags: scala, future, slick

I am trying to query a MySQL database asynchronously using Slick. The following code template, which I use to query about 90k rows in a for comprehension, seems to be working initially, but the program consumes several gigabytes of RAM and fails without warning after around 200 queries.

```
import scala.slick.jdbc.{StaticQuery => Q}
def doQuery(): Future[List[String]] = future {
  val q = "select name from person"
  db withSession {
    Q.query[String](q).list
  }
}
```

I have tried setting up connections both using the `fromURL` method and also using a c3p0 connection pool. My question is: Is this the way to do asynchronous calls to the database?

Comment: What's the behavior if you use `db withSession { implicit session :Session =>`? FYI, `threadLocalSession` is discouraged.

Comment: What (and how) can I use instead of a `threadLocalSession` or where can I find documentation of what session types are available?

Comment: Get the session from the withSession call instead as I wrote `db withSession { implicit session :Session =>`

Comment: The problem was that in the code above `db` represents a database connection rather than a session. I assumed that since most (all?) documentation examples use `db` when performing queries, that would actually be the session. It now works great, see also comment on the [related Github issue](https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/44#issuecomment-28196768).

Answer (score 4):

Async is still an [open issue for Slick](https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/44).

You could try using Iterables and stream data instead of storing it in memory with a solution similar to this: [Treating an SQL ResultSet like a Scala Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636545/treating-an-sql-resultset-like-a-scala-stream)

Although please omit the .toStream call at the end. It will cache the data in memory, while Iterable will not.

If you want an async version of iterable you could look into [Observables](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/wiki).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for pointing me to the issue. See also [my comment](https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/44#issuecomment-28196768)

Comment: Glad I could point you in the right direction. Your solution is nice, good job ;)

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that this is a non issue (actually a bug in my code, which opened a new database connection for each query). In my experience, you can wrap DB queries in Futures as shown above and compose them later with [Scala Async](https://github.com/scala/async) or [Rx](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/), as shown [here](https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/44#issuecomment-28196768). All is required for good performance is a large thread pool (x2 the CPUs in my case) and an equally large connection pool.

Answer (score 1):

[Slick 3 (Reactive Slick)](http://slick.typesafe.com/news/2015/04/02/slick-3.0.0-RC3-released.html) looks like it might address this.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.