# Any better, more idiomatic way to convert SQL ResultSet to a Scala List or other collection type?

Tags: scala, jdbc

I'm using the following naive code to convert a `ResultSet` to a Scala `List`:

```
val rs = pstmt.executeQuery()
var nids = List[String]()
while (rs.next()) {
  nids = nids :+ rs.getString(1)
}
rs.close()
```

Is there a better approach, something more idiomatic to Scala, that doesn't require using a mutable object?

Comment: Why don't you use a mapper library like Slick or Quill? It would make your life easier!

Comment: I use it in Spark executors, so I prefer synchronous mode; and as I need to use the PostGIS extension to Postgres, a Plain SQL is much easier to start with. So I come back to old JDBC connections.

Comment: Dont know it helps but use this                                                  
      query.execute
      query.getResultList.asScala.toList

Comment: http://playframework.github.io/anorm/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why don't you try this:

```
new Iterator[String] {
  def hasNext = resultSet.next()
  def next() = resultSet.getString(1)
}.toStream
```

Taken from this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636545/treating-an-sql-resultset-like-a-scala-stream)

Comment: When I use this function, and then "map" over the Iterator (to create an object from the columns returned - (or use a for-comprehension /yield) and then tack on a .toVector - my vector always ends up missing the first record.

Comment: How do I convert more than one columns from the resultset into Arrays? next() would remove elements from the Iterator

Comment: You can return a Tuple in next =>   def next() = (resultSet.getString(1), resultSet.getString(2))

Comment: @GavinBaumanis is right :I am doing
  new Iterator[Employee] {
      def hasNext = rs.next()
      def next() = Employee(rs.getString("name"), rs.getInt("age"))
    }.toStream.                             and it is skipping one record

Answer (score 8):

I have a similar problem and my solution is:

`Iterator.from(0).takeWhile(_ => rs.next()).map(_ => rs.getString(1)).toList`

Hope that will help.

Comment: I think this way of doing, skips one record

Answer (score 0):

Using ORM tool like `slick` or `Quill` as mention in comment section is considered to be better approach.

If you want to use the Scala Code for processing the ResultSet.You can use the `tailRecursion`.

> ```
> @scala.annotation.tailrec
> def getResult(resultSet: ResultSet, list: List[String] = Nil): List[String] = {
>   if (resultSet.next()) {
>     val value = resultSet.getString(0)
>     getResult(resultSet, value :: list)
>   }
>   else {
>     list
>   }
> }
> ```

This method returns the list of string that contains column value at 0th position. This process is pure immutable so you don't need to worry.On the plus side this method is tail recursion so Scala will internally optimize this method accordingly.

Thanks

Comment: Using an ORM is hardly the "best approach". It depends on the type and size of the project, and usually introduces a complexity that isn't always worth the trouble.

Comment: Agree, @Kraylog. Actually I'm using PostGIS extensions to PostgreSQL, for spatial and geographic query; there're some DSL functions, which I would probably not feel comfortable with ORM.

Comment: I have select query with 40 fields , can I apply this logic to fetch all the fields ?